# How to include Oracle SQL required single qoutes in preparedstatement

Tags: java

I am attempting to successfully execute the sql query presented below within a generated preparedstatement object that will retrieve data from a oracle database for which the timestamp column value is within the last x minutes.  I was informed by our project Oracle database administrator that use of the systimestamp - INTERVAL 'x' MINUTE clause is the way to go.  I am running into the following issues:

1) If I include this clause as indicated with the parameter question mark in single quotes ('?') and attempt to update it with the preparedstatement setString method I get an Invalid Index error.

2) If I remove the single quotes around the parameter question mark I am able to update it with the preparedstatement setString method but when it is executed Oracle returns an invalid INTERVAL error.

The single quotes are required by Oracle for this where clause to be valid.  I know there are other ways to generate the required sql to get the desired results without using the INTERVAL clause, but since my program DBA indicated this is the most efficient way to go I would like to get it to work within a preparedstatement since the resulting query could happen a lot of times.  And before you ask this DBA does not know how to write Java code or use the available preparedstatement interface.

Any assistance is always greatly appreciated.

select * from table where timestamp_col > systimestamp - INTERVAL '?' MINUTE

Comment: Why don't you just use java.time to create the appropriate timestamp instead?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setString` - would `INTERVAL 'ALOHA!' MINUTES` make sense? Instead use `setInt`.

And the single quotes when present convert the parameter to a single-character string ('?' in this case).

Answer (score 0):

don't put the ? in quotes.  the quotes denote a literal whereas the ? is a parameter.  Also instead of using setString, I'd assume you'd want to use setInt for a numeric value

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

```
int numMinutes = 5; //some number
String queryString = "select * from table where timestamp_col > systimestamp - INTERVAL ? MINUTE";
PreparedStatement query = con.prepareStatement(queryString);
query.setInt(1, numMinutes);
```

Comment: I tried the recommended change but still get an Oracle error when attempting to execute the query without the single quotes around the specified numerical value for minutes.  Oracle requires the single quotes for the INTERVAL clause. The end result of this query is to return only those rows for which the timestamp column's value is within the specified number of minutes provided by the user on a GUI.  If the provided value is 10 minutes I want the query to return all rows for which the timestamp column's value is within 10 minutes of the current time.

Comment: Fixed sql to perform as required with following: select * from table where timestamp_col > systimestamp - ?/(24*60) , where I replace the ? parameter with desired number of minutes as input by user on GUI.